# Using hook_form_alter to add a label/placeholder insider a form <input> tag

Tags: forms, commerce

using Drupal Commerce checkout form there is a default 'address' field (it's dynamic and includes several fields in one that are not easy to separate - such as country, name, address 1 and 2, state, etc.). I turned off the labels for the address field because they are ugly and I'd like to put the labels INSIDE each  tag, as you would normally do with html like so:

HTML 5:

```
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
```

Where the 'placeholder' property shows what should be entered into the field within the  tag, thus removing the need to have a separate label at all.

Anyone know how to do this (include a placeholder property if you will) with hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify placeholder attribute in '#attributes' array like this:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
    $form['item']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder text');
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems reasonable but didn't work for me. I know I'm accessing the correct fields because I'm using the same field names as when I organized the fields by their '#weight' in my hook form alter module. For example, I have $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_title']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('title');

Comment: Hmm, that's wired becouse It work's for me.

Please, check this code - http://codepad.org/iAV0gkvG This is alter for node add form. And also try to check if field of array is valid name. Maybe use dsm() function from devel module to print $form, and check if everything is ok in this array. If it's maybe you have some other module which alter forms? Or some JS?

Comment: `$form['item']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder text');` will work only for default fields. For custom fields, you need to specify like `$form['item'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder text');`